# Why is this method not removing elements from an array

Tags: java, file, arraylist

I have a scanner reading a txt of a webpage into an arraylist. Each line of the template is one element in the arraylist.
I then have a loop that is removing elements from the list if the the character at index 1 is my target element.
My question is why are some elements being removed and others are not?
Code below

```
public static ArrayList<String> adjustTemplate(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> consecutiveCountsByGroup) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File referenceFile = new File("C:\\Users\\chris\\Documents\\SoundlineFiles\\SoundlineFormater\\format.txt");    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(referenceFile);
    ArrayList<String> template = new ArrayList();

    //add template to arraylist
    int index=0;
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {              
        template.add(scanner.nextLine());
        index++;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<template.size();i++) {                    //for template size

        if(template.get(i).charAt(1)=='h'   ||  template.get(i).charAt(1)=='l'  ||  template.get(i).charAt(1)=='p') {   //if char at 1 is an h,l or p

            if(template.get(i).charAt(1)=='h' ){
                template.remove(i);
            }

            if(template.get(i).charAt(1)=='l' ){
                template.remove(i);
            }

            if(template.get(i).charAt(1)=='p' ){
                template.remove(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(template.get(i));
    }
    return template;
}
```

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I3Z8.png)

Comment: Try printing template.get(i).charAt(1) in the for loop to see where it goes wrong

Comment: have you debugged your code?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is why are some elements being removed and others are not?

When you remove an element this way, the size of the list decreases immediately e.g. assume a list has the elements as follows:

```
list(0) -> help
list(1) -> pulp
list(2) -> ram
```

Now if you execute `list(0).remove`, the size of the list decreases to `2` and also the elements after the deleted element are shifted back i.e. the list becomes like:

```
list(0) -> pulp
list(1) -> ram
```

i.e. when the value of `i` will become `1`, `list(1).remove` will remove `ram` (and not `pulp`).

I hope, it is clear. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt.

Comment: Yes. Also, your code can remove up to three elements in one iteration. If the last element starts with an 'h', you can get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are modifying the size of the list while you are reading, you have changed the original value of the list, so it won't remove all the elements.

There are many ways to solve this, one of them is using an Iterator instead of the for.

```
public static ArrayList<String> adjustTemplate(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> consecutiveCountsByGroup) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File referenceFile = new File("file.html");    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(referenceFile);
    ArrayList<String> template = new ArrayList();

    //add template to arraylist
    int index=0;
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {              
        template.add(scanner.nextLine());
        index++;
    }

    Iterator i = template.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        String line = (String) i.next();
        if(line.charAt(1)=='h'   ||  line.charAt(1)=='l'  ||  line.charAt(1)=='p') {
            i.remove();
        }
    }

    for(String s : template) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    return template;
}
```

My Input:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<i>Example</i>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<div>Dont remove</div>
<l>Remove pls</l>
</body>
</html>
```

My output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<i>Example</i>
<div>Dont remove</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your this source code:

```
for(int i=0;i<template.size();i++) {                    //for template size

    if(template.get(i).charAt(1)=='h'   ||  template.get(i).charAt(1)=='l'  ||  template.get(i).charAt(1)=='p') {   //if char at 1 is an h,l or p

        if(template.get(i).charAt(1)=='h' ){
            template.remove(i);
        }

        if(template.get(i).charAt(1)=='l' ){
            template.remove(i);
        }

        if(template.get(i).charAt(1)=='p' ){
            template.remove(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(template.get(i));
}
```

into this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList();
for(int i=0;i<template.size();i++) {                    //for template size

    if(template.get(i).charAt(1)=='h'   ||  template.get(i).charAt(1)=='l'  ||  template.get(i).charAt(1)=='p') {   //if char at 1 is an h,l or p
        temp.add(i);
    }
}

for(int i=0;i<temp.size();i++) {                    //for temp size
    template.remove(i);
}
```

You don't need to check double conditions